# How to console.log to the background page from chrome extantion?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write to the console of the background page (from popup)

```
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().console.log('hello');
```

this code seems not to work...

Comment: There's no background page in ManifestV3 extension.

Comment: I use manifest V2
But still there is any way to console.log to the webpage and not to the extention popup?

Comment: Try with `chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(bgpage=>{bgpage.console.log('hello');})`.

Comment: "runtime.lastError: You do not have a background page."
when you mean background page do you mean the webpage where i open the extention?  becouse that what i need, to console.log to the webpage console and not the the popup console

Comment: That is different. In order to do that, you have to inject a content script to the active page and that content script can then log to the console. Something like `chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:'console.log("hello")'})`.

Comment: I would recommend you to not waste time with manifest v2, start with Manifest V3 because next year Manifest V2 extensions won't work, so you will be wasting your time.

Comment: I will try, 
Do you know a good way to write to the console but with code?
for example - I need to write console.log(let x = 2) in the console from my script, but i need that the X will be a real variable and not just a string

Comment: I'd recommend you take a look at the content script documentation for [MV2](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/content_scripts/) or [MV3](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)